# Получить значение из БД по имени и фамилии пользователя

Tags: java, jdbc

Использую бд mysql, необходимо получить значение из БД по имени и фамлии пользователя.

```
private static User ReadUser(String GetByName,String GetBySurname) throws SQLException {
        String query = "select * from users";
        Statement statement = dbWorker.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        User newUser = new User();
        while (resultSet.next()){
            if(resultSet.getString("name").equals(GetByName) && resultSet.getString("surname").equals(GetBySurname)){
                newUser.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                newUser.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                newUser.setSurname(resultSet.getString("surname"));
                newUser.setDate(resultSet.getString("date"));
                newUser.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
                newUser.setSocials(resultSet.getString("socials"));
            }
        }
        return newUser;
    }
```

Если я пытаюсь написать в запрос `select * from users where name = GetByName, surname = GetBySurname` не получается так написать. Написал такой метод, он работает, получает, но лучше сделать это запросом. Подскажите как нужно переписать запрос, чтобы туда можно было передать значения которые передаются в метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
String query = "select * from users where name = ? and surname = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = dbWorker.getConnection().prepareStatement(query)
statement.setString(1, GetByName);
statement.setString(2, GetBySurname);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
    newUser.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
    newUser.setSurname(resultSet.getString("surname"));
    newUser.setDate(resultSet.getString("date"));
    newUser.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
    newUser.setSocials(resultSet.getString("socials"));
    users.add(newUser);
}
// в users - список пользователей, которые нашлись по имени и фамилии
```